# Can I transfer music to my Lumia phone without using the Zune software?

Tags: windows, zune

I'd much rather avoid installing Zune on my Windows PC if I can easily avoid it, I simply want to dump MP3s on/off it.

It would be kind of nice if I could just use Windows Media Player... is there a neat way to make my phone (a 610 in my case) show up in Windows Explorer somehow?

Comment: While [registry edits](http://nokiarevolution.com/2012/09/21/trick-how-to-enable-usb-mass-storage-mode-in-lumia-devices/) can help enable **mass storage mode**, the [USB Storage Enabler tool](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln5U4.jpg) makes it [easy](http://nokiarevolution.com/tricks-and-tips/usb-storage-enabler-for-windows-phones-77-8/) (get the latest version [here](http://ultimate-networx.net/?page_id=258&lang=en)). Unfortunately looks like Zune needs to be installed for it to work.

Comment: Starting with WP8, phones show up as devices in Explorer.

Comment: Think this has been asked already here?

http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-sync-wp8-with-windows

Answer (score 2):

You may wirelessly transfer/copy music files to your Windows Phone via a web browser using the current version of [Music Drop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/music-drop/09a12ce5-26ec-4251-b7a1-16216de4c2fb). It's free and fast.

Comment: This was great, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good guide on [How to Enable USB Mass Storage mode in Lumia devices](http://www.nokiarevolution.com/tricks-and-tips/how-to-enable-usb-mass-storage-mode-in-lumia-devices/).

Comment: You should provide at least brief summary of the contents of the link. Sooner or later that link will be broken, and after that this answer is pretty much useless.